# Can't get jquery validation to work with dynamic mvc Html helpers

Tags: c#, validation, razor, model-binding, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I generate a form from the database and I'd like to use mvc htmlhelpers to help me out. And surprisingly, this works out pretty well.

```
@model Models.MyViewModelWithACollectionOfFormElements

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @foreach (var item in Model.FormItems)
    {
        @Html.Editor(item.Name, item.EditorTemplate, item.HtmlAttributes)

        // "validate_" gets prefixed before the 'id' and 'name' attributes.
        @Html.ValidationMessage(item.Name, item.GetHtmlAttributes("validate_"))
    }
}
```

(Stripped out the code that outputs the dropdownlists conditionally, but you get the idea).

The resulting html is as follows:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" id="MyName" name="MyName" type="number" value="" />            
<span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="MyName" data-valmsg-replace="true" id="validate_MyName" name="validate_MyName"></span>
```

And all this gets binded nicely and is posted to my controller when I click submit. BUT, I'd also like to get jquery validation to work and as you might have noticed, the html.editor helper does not output the ...

```
data-val="true" data-val-number="The field MyName must be a number." data-val-required="The MyName field is required."
```

... attributes for me in the input element. Which is why it is ignored by the unobtrusive jquery validate scripting. So my question: How can I get these attributes from the helper in a dynamically generated form?

Comment: Does your model class have the validation attributes (e.g. `[Required]`) set?

Comment: Yes they do, but since the form is dynamic and the helper isn't directly provided with the model, it doesn't 'see' the annotations attributes. I would be cool if there was another way of providing those restrictions to the helper.

Comment: Maybe you could pass those restriction in the `ViewBag` and write a custom `HtmlHelper` that encapsulate `Html.Editor` rendering the data attributes for the validation too.

Comment: That's a solution I was thinking of, but I was hoping for a simpler one. Doing it myself would include all of the scenarios the Html.Editor can render (number, checkbox, and so and) and all of the annotations there can be (number, min, max, nullable and so on)

Comment: Moreover, bear in mind that Html.Editor will not render the data-val-* attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work. Put the Editor and Validation message in it's own partial view (I've called it `_FormItem` here)

```
@foreach (var item in Model.FormItems)
{
    @Html.RenderPartial("_FormItem", item)
}
```

In the partial view `_FormItem` do this:

```
@model Models.FormItem

@Html.Editor(Model.Name, Model.EditorTemplate, Model.HtmlAttributes)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, null, Model.GetHtmlAttributes("validate_"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar functionality in my application.What you need to do is create a sub-model class that stores elements of your "FormItems", and then add [Required] to every needed element.

In your main Model you should have something like this:

```
IList<FormItemModel> FormItems { get; set; }
```

Then in FormItemModel

```
public class FormItemModel
{
    [Required]
    public string? Name
}
```

And then in view loop through the FormItems (I hard-coded 10 elements in the loop but you can create as many as you need, when initializing main Model class)

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FormItems[i].Name)
}
```